# What is the difference between bson.son.SON and collections.OrderedDict?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

The bson.son.SON is used mainly in pymongo, to get a ordered mapping(dict).

But python already have the ordered dict in collections.OrderedDict()

I have read the docs of bson.son.SON. It did say SON is similar to OrderedDict but did not mention the difference.

So What is the difference? When should we use SON and when should we use OrderedDict?

Comment: by docs `SON provides an API similar to collections.OrderedDict from Python 2.7+.` More details you can find use `dir` and read source.

Comment: Thanks @BearBrown The docs did not mention the difference. What I want to know is why we have SON when python already have the OrderedDict

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the slight difference in both is that [`bson.son.SON`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/3.7.1/bson/son.py) remains backward compatible with Python 2.7 and [older versions](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/pull/238#issuecomment-45345259).
Also the argument that `SON` serializes faster than `OrderedDict` is no longer correct in 2018.

The `son` module was [added in Jan 8, 2009](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/bd49bf50208b0e409ee0d1b01b91b66ff14200f5/son.py).

`collections.OrderedDict`(PEP-372) was added in python in [Mar 2, 2009](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2d32f63ec9bef3c78144557e5b2984f9b56a3294/Lib/collections.py).

While the differences in dates doesn't tell which was released first, it is interesting to see that the Mongodb already implemented an ordered map for their use case. I guess that they may have decided to keep maintaining it for backward compatibility instead of switching all `SON` references in their codebase to `collections.OrderedDict`

In small experiments with both, you easily see that `collections.OrderedDict` performs better than `bson.son.SON`.

```
In [1]:    from bson.son import SON
           from collections import OrderedDict
           import copy

           print(set(dir(SON)) - set(dir(OrderedDict)))
```

> {'**weakref**', 'iteritems', 'iterkeys', 'itervalues', '**module**', 'has_key', '**deepcopy**', 'to_dict'}

```
In [2]:    %timeit s = SON([('a',2)]); z = copy.deepcopy(s)
```

> 14.3 µs ± 758 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

```
In [3]:    %timeit s = OrderedDict([('a',2)]); z = copy.deepcopy(s)
```

> 7.54 µs ± 209 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

```
In [4]:    %timeit s = SON(data=[('a',2)]); z = json.dumps(s)
```

> 11.5 µs ± 350 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

```
In [5]:    %timeit s = OrderedDict([('a',2)]); z = json.dumps(s)
```

> 5.35 µs ± 192 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In answer to your question about when to use SON,
use SON if running your software in versions of Python older than `2.7`.

If you can help it, use `OrderedDict` from the `collections` module. 
You can also use `dict`, they are ordered now in [Python 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/5189811)